# Android: Writing XML file creates 2 files if whitespace is present in file name

Tags: android, xml

edit: Found my problem!

Found my problem !

I actually had two calls to create new files:

```
if (!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
```

and

```
Result result = new StreamResult(f);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Without whitespace in the file name, everything went well as they both treated the same files. However, with whitespace, StreamResult encodes the file name as a URL (therefore with %20 replacing spaces) whereas createNewFile() does not. The fix was simple. I removed the

```
f.createNewFile();
```

line and added:

```
result.setSystemId(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(result.getSystemId(), "UTF-8"));
```

therefore writing the filename correctly with spaces.

**Original question:**

I am trying to write a XML file, but the following code seems to produce two different files if there is whitespace in the file name. The first file will be named correctly with whitespace, the other one will have its whitespace replaced by %20. **Only the file with the whitespace replaced (%20) seems to have the correct XML content**. It seems to be related to URL encoding, but I can't seem to figure out where it's happening.

```
public String export(Context ctx) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder icBuilder;
    try {
        icBuilder = icFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = icBuilder.newDocument();
        Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("deck");
        mainRootElement.setAttribute("game",
                "0f38e453-26df-4c04-9d67-6d43de939c77");
        doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);

        // identity card is located on top of the XML file

        // identity section
        Element identitySection = doc.createElement("section");
        identitySection.setAttribute("name", CardTypes.IDENTITY);
        mainRootElement.appendChild(identitySection);
        identitySection
                .appendChild(createNode(doc, 1, identity.getTitle()));

        // stack / r&d section
        Element deckSection = doc.createElement("section");
        deckSection.setAttribute("name", "R&D / Stack");
        // add all the cards!
        for (DeckItem item : cards) {
            NRCard card = item.getCard();
            deckSection.appendChild(createNode(doc, item.getAmount(),
                    card.getTitle()));
        }
        mainRootElement.appendChild(deckSection);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        if (Utilities.ExternalStorageWritable()) {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            File f = new File(root + "/TheToolbox/decks/" + this.deckName
                    + ".o8d");
            if (!f.getParentFile().exists())
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();

            Result result = new StreamResult(f);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            System.out.println("Export completed");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("External storage not writable");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TB error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return this.deckName;
}
```

Comment: `but the following code seems to produce two different files`  Does it produce two separate files?  What do you mean "seems to"?  Are you talking about the content of the files or the filenames?

Comment: Yes, it created two files. One with whitespace, one without. Found my problem ! StreamResult encodes the file name whereas file.createNewFile does not. Will update my question.

Comment: If you found the answer, you should really submit it as an answer, rather than edit the question.

Comment: Indeed! As I have low reputation though, I could not answer my own question within 8 hours of it being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem !

I actually had two calls to create new files:

```
if (!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
```

and

```
Result result = new StreamResult(f);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Without whitespace in the file name, everything went well as they both treated the same files. However, with whitespace, StreamResult encodes the file name as a URL (therefore with %20 replacing spaces) whereas createNewFile() does not. The fix was simple. I removed the

```
f.createNewFile();
```

line and added:

```
result.setSystemId(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(result.getSystemId(), "UTF-8"));
```

therefore writing the filename correctly with spaces.